# Other solution (or solutions) for Kill process or end process in android

Tags: java, android, process, background, kill-process

I spend 1 month searching about this theme.

> How to kill processes of other apps in android.

All solutions that I found not solved my problem:

> Preclude a user start a app that not is in my list.

I try:

```
"killBackgroundProcesses(packageName);"
and
"forceStopPackage.invoke(am, process.processName);"
```

But nothing happens. So, how can I put in background or end the activity? I'm developing to 4.4.x android version. Any comment will be welcome. Hugs.

[@Edit]
I know: to kill processes in android is a bad idea. So what I do to blocking my users of see others apps?

Comment: You mean kill other processes? Not yours?

Comment: Yes! I try to kill processes of other apps, but nothing happens.

Comment: Posted answer, hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to kill other applications from your application has to be a "root application" or a system application, meaning that you get special privileges. (Without special privileges, you can only kill a process that has the same userID as the one that is doing the killing. If you are trying to kill your own process it should work.)

Here is a site with details on permissions: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html

Most third party apps do not get special privileges.

If everyone were allowed to kill each other's applications, it would be chaotic.

Quote:

> " Android has no mechanism for granting permissions dynamically (at run-time) because it complicates the user experience to the detriment of security."

Comment: Nothing new for me. I read in others comments what you posted. I want other solution for "Kill processes". Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @FelipeCosta The thing is, You cant. Here is another question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007152/how-to-gain-root-privileges-to-block-another-app-on-android/28007231#28007231

Comment: The point is: I don't want to kill processes, I just want to block my users from see others apps.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007152/how-to-gain-root-privileges-to-block-another-app-on-android/28007231#28007231

Comment: So, views or put in background does not work? (You repeat the link..)